# How to download a static file during npm install

Tags: javascript, angular, npm

I have a link in my angular app which upon clicking should open a pdf file. But, this file should first be downloaded and to make it statically available.

Is there a way to download a file via http request while running npm install?

Basically, before hosting the app I need to download and copy a file to a static location which is then referred to from the href within the app

Something like

```
npm download http://download.com/file.pdf
```

or

```
instruct npm to download via paclage.json
```

Answer (score 1):

You can define a  `postinstall` script in your app's package.json :

**package.json**

```json
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node src/index.js",
    "postinstall": "node downloadAssets.js", // <--------------------------
    // ...
  },
  "dependencies": { /* ... */ }
  // ...
}
```

And then create a script to do it:

**downloadAssets.js**

```
const http = require('http');
const fs = require('fs');

const file = fs.createWriteStream("file.pdf");
http.get("http://download.com/file.pdf", function(response) {
  response.pipe(file);
});
```

It will be executed when you install your app (after everything is installed)